# Remove back button Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to remove the back button from navigation bar of my pages. Is there any way to do so

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest way to remove back button in Ionic

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton *navbar>< /ion-navbar>
```

Comment: so did you try this answer in ionic 2

Answer (score 4):

```
 <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
```

include this in your ion-navbar .. the back button  will be excluded for your current view

Answer (score 3):

To remove the back button on `this.navCtrl.push` in your app.module.ts file

do this

```
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonText:'',
      backButtonIcon:''
    }, {}
  )],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp ],
  providers: []
})
```

take a look at this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/

another way is you should use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(pagename,{});`

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing with this approch

Comment: This does not remove the button it simply has no icon nor text but the user can still click on it and navigate back.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use
[ion-toolbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/toolbar/Toolbar/)

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Header</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

instead of navbar.
Note: User will still be able to go back through the phone back button.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ion-toolbar instead of ion-navbar.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button left menuToggle="MyMenu">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>My Awosome App</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better go for `$ionicNavBarDelegate`
This will helps to configure your backbutton.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/